# Scrapy: Unable to fetch information on Urls that reached the max retries

Tags: scrapy

I'm getting a lot of 503 from a site I am **scraping** with Scrapy and I can't get it to record a list of all the failures.

I've enabled the Retry module using RETRY_ENABLED = True and set RETRY_TIMES = 2 for testing purposes.

I've added the from_crawler class method and registered two callbacks but none are being called.

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_error, signal=signals.item_error)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_dropped, signal=signals.item_dropped)

    return spider

def item_error(self, item, response, spider, failure):
        self.log("************************ ERROR ********", logging.ERROR)
        self.log(item, logging.ERROR)

def item_dropped(self, item, response, exception, spider):
        self.log("*********************** DROPPED *********", logging.ERROR)
        self.log(item, logging.ERROR)
```

The callbacks are not called when a URL failed with or without exception

Answer (score 0):

To handle an error response, [use the `errback` parameter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks) of the [`Request` constructor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).